# Set thumb image position of UISlider in iOS

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, uislider

Is there any way to set thumb image position of UISlider irrespective of  slider value? For example,  slider value  can be anything between 0 - 100, but i want to keep thumb image at position 20. Is it possible to achieve this with the default UISlider rather than creating a custom slider? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Why would you want the thumb to ignore the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to subclass `UISlider` and override `thumbRectForBounds:trackRect:value:` to return a custom frame for the thumb. Not sure what purpose this would serve by your description though...

---

Based on your comment, the above is not the approach you want to take. Instead, your view controller should add itself as the target for the `valueChanged` (`UIControlEventValueChanged`) actions coming from the slider.

In this method, determine the appropriate rounded value from the slider's value and then use `setValue:animated:` to move the slider thumb to the appropriate place.

Comment: Hello Wain, thanks for your answer. The reason why i want this because i need to move thumb image (discrete movement, rather than continuos) only when slider value passed a particular position. Like i have 10 points in slider like 10, 20,30 .... 90,100 , i want the thumb image only move to a particular point if slider value is greater than that point, like for slider value  10-19 thumb image will remain in 1st point (10). Is there any better way to accomplish this?